# How long does guardian potion last, and how much damage reduction does it provide?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

The item description is very vague, simply stating what it does without any specifics. I'd rather not spend 200 rupees on it if it only provides a slight reduction for less than a minute.

How much damage reduction does it provide, and how long does it last?

Comment: And be sure to carry the Potion Medal (Skipper's Retreat Goddess Cube) so the effect of your buffs last twice as long - or 3 times in fact, I'm not sure - that might be only in the Boss Battle mode.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It just reduces the amount of damage you take by half.  It lasts for 3 minutes.

I would infuse it instead of using it as is.  When infused as **Guardian Potion+**, you are invulnerable for 3 minutes instead.